# Titlesec and \ref do not match

Tags: cross-referencing, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to modify how the sections are numbered. The problem is that when I label it and refer latter, the reference will use the standard section number.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Alph{section}.}{0.3em}{}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section}\label{section}

  \ref{section} $\leftarrow$ wrong!
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

(the expected behaviour is, of course, that the reference produce "A", not "1").

I checked the documentation of `titlesec` as well the "Similar Questions" suggested by Stack Exchange and I cannot find the answer. Please, forgive me if the answer is evident and I missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\ref` accesses to the representation of the counter provided by `\thesection`. So you have to change the meaning of this command, rather than using `\Alph{section}` in `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {0.3em}
  {}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section}\label{section}

  \ref{section} $\leftarrow$ right!
\end{document}
```

[image]